# XOR "^" in Java is generating unexpected result

Tags: java

I'm trying to do XOR with this Java statement, but it's generating unexpected output.

```
System.out.println(0x15C ^ 0x11B);
```

Output:

```
71
```

However, if I go to http://www.jdejong.net/tools/bitwisecalculator.php, the output is 47.

[image]

If I do this by hand, I get the result 0x47.

```
0x15C: 000101011100
0x11B: 000100011011
---------------------- XOR
0x47:  000001000111
```

How do I generate 47 (what I believe to be the correct answer) using Java?

---

**EDIT:**
Answer:
Forgot that it was decimal, not hex. The screenshot's XOR Result confused me since it didn't have 0x notation.

Comment: You didn't format the output as hex, so it output in decimal. 0x47 = 71.

Comment: In general, any time you assert that "XXX in language YYY is broken", you're making a fool of yourself.  Better to phrase it as "I know I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what."

Comment: What gets me about stackoverflow is that a question like this gets downvoted to oblivion, while a million questions about how to bind a click event in javascript get an upvote because they're easy and they'll get answeres points. I mean sure, you overlooked something, but by its nature it was not a terrible question as your downvotes would suggest.

Comment: Don't be so quick to accuse an extensively established language like Java. Always doubt yourself first. [It's always your fault.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Comment: @pep - I think Opie got downvoted more because he said "Java is broken" than because he asked a "dumb" question.

Comment: Yes, I can't disagree the question is not eloquently asked. And I also live by the policy of "doubt yourself first" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0x47 (hexadecimal) is 71 (decimal). If you want your integer to be printed in hexadecimal notation, use [Integer.toHexString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-)

Answer (score 12):

The output is correct. 71 is the decimal representation for 0x47.
If you want to print it in hex, I propose to use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). For example:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%#x",0x15C ^ 0x11B));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     101011100
XOR  100011011
      --------
     001000111
```

**71** (in decimal) is correct

Answer (score 0):

It's just a number.  By default, numbers are printed as decimal (base 10).

```
   71 = 0x47
```